# WebEngineView input focus detection (omitting QVirtualKeyboard)

Tags: qml, qt5, qwebengineview

I embedded a basic QML based virtual keyboard in my QML WebEngineView app, due to many problems I had with using plugin-based virtual keyboards across various devices (like QVirtualKeyboard or other, free alternatives that rely on private Qt headers). Using `postEvent` on `QGuiApplication::focusObject()` works perfect.

Only problem I have is to detect the moment when to show the virtual keyboard. So far I used `WebChannel` to communicate from a global `focus` event listener.

```
QtObject {
        id: qmlKeyboard
        WebChannel.id: "qmlKeyboard"

        function show(type) {
               keyboard.visible = true
        }
}
WebEngineScript {
        id: keyboardScript
        name: "qt_vkscript"
        injectionPoint: WebEngineScript.DocumentReady
        sourceUrl: "qrc:///vkscript.js"
        worldId: WebEngineScript.MainWorld
        runOnSubframes: true // doesnt work as it should
}

WebEngineScript {
        id: webChannelScript
        name: "QWebChannel"
        sourceUrl: "qrc:///qtwebchannel/qwebchannel.js"
        injectionPoint: WebEngineScript.DocumentCreation
        worldId: WebEngineScript.MainWorld
        runOnSubframes: true
}
```

```js
new QWebChannel(qt.webChannelTransport, function(channel) {
    window.qmlKeyboard = channel.objects.qmlKeyboard;
    document.addEventListener('focus', function(e) {
        // rest of code omitted as it's not relevant

        qmlKeyboard.show();
    }, true);
    document.addEventListener('blur', function(){qmlKeyboard.hide();}, true);
});
```

And this works, but there is a small **problem**: it does not work on iframes in the loaded page.

Adding `runOnSubframes: true` causes a `qt is not defined` error in JS due to `qt.webChannelTransport` being undefined, even though `qwebchannel.js` is included. Same happens when using a different world for the `WebEngineScript` (which IMO is a Qt bug). I found some info it could be caused by Qt Quick compiler, but I have it disabled in my `.pro` file.

Is there any way to get `WebChannel` working across iframes too (solve the `qt is not defined` error) or somehow detect that user input is requested from `WebEngineView` natively, like the real virtual keyboard does, but without using any private headers that cause version mismatch problems later?
I tried using `focusChanged` but that's about changing focus of QT widgets (so the entire webview).

**Update**
So far I have tried installing an event filter on my app to look for anything useful, there is a `QInputMethodQueryEvent` when focusing but doesn't help.
I found this interesting article: https://www.kdab.com/qt-input-method-depth/ which explains it deeply, but again leads to `QPlatformInputContext` which is a private API...

There's also https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qinputmethod.html available in `QGuiApplication` but I found nothing useful here

Answer (score 0):

So far, I have worked around this problem by installing the `qwebchannel.js` script only on the top-most document, and adding my custom script with `runOnSubframes: true` and communicating with the top-most parent (`window.top`) from iframes using `window.top.postMessage()`.

Basically something like this:

```js
if (typeof QWebChannel !== 'undefined') {
    new QWebChannel(qt.webChannelTransport, function(channel) {
      window.qmlKeyboard = channel.objects.qmlKeyboard;
    });
    window.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
      if (e.data === 'showkeyboard')
        qmlKeyboard.show();
      else if (e.data === 'hidekeyboard')
        qmlKeyboard.hide();
    });
}

document.addEventListener('focus', function(e) {
    // ....
    if(qmlKeyboard)
        qmlKeyboard.show();
    else window.top.postMessage('showkeyboard', '*');
}, true);
```

It works fine so far for me, sad there is no simpler way (that I know of) to catch software input requests without messing with private Qt plugin APIs but it is what it is.